# Hive date functions within create table

Tags: hive, hbase, hiveql

My hive version is 1.2.0

I am doing hive hbase integration where my hbase table already present.

While creating hive table, I was checking if I can use few of hive's built-in date functions as a candidate for virtual columns/derived columns, which is something like this -

```
create external table `Hive_Test`(

*existing hbase columns*,

*new_column* AS to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(*existing_column*,'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')...

)CLUSTERED BY (..) SORTED BY (new_colulmn) INTO n BUCKETS

..
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES(
hbase.columns.mappings=':key,cf:*,:timestamp',
..
)
```

If there is any other way where I can use built-in functions capability in create table, then please let me know. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to create a view on top of the non-native table created for Hive-HBase integration, with which you can do almost any kind of mapping that facilitates your business.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to - [Hive Computed Column](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-partition-Hive-table-with-a-computed-column/td-p/229988), i think you are defining a logic when creating a table which is not possible with hive.

You can refer this article for [Apache Hive Derived Column Support and Alternative](https://dwgeek.com/apache-hive-derived-column-support-and-alternative.html/)